# Como carregar alterações feitas em classes nativas do java?

Tags: java, java-ee, prepared-statement

**Olá**,

Estou tentando executar um arquivo jar, substituindo algumas interfaces originais do java para conexão com o banco de dados, alterando o método setBoolean para receber um objeto como parâmetro.

**Original**:

```
void setBoolean(int parameterIndex, boolean x) throws SQLException;
```

**Minha mudança:**

```
void setBoolean(int parameterIndex, Boolean x) throws SQLException;
```

Minhas mudanças foram feitas na classe PreparedStatement para que as minhas alterações sejam chamadas, ao iniciar a aplicação estou usando o comando:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:C:/Users/elizio/Desktop/safepdv700/safepdv700/src/main/java -jar safepdv.jar
```

Por do "-verbose:class" consigo verificar que ele chega a carregar a classe com minhas alterações.

Porém, quando o setBoolean é chamado pela aplicação, ele não encontra o método, me retornando:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\rt.jar]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.sql.PreparedStatement.setBoolean(IZ)V
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.controller.ConfiguracaoController.updateCS(ConfiguracaoController.java:613)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.MovimentoAberto.validaCamposLogin(MovimentoAberto.java:448)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.MovimentoAberto.passwordTextSenhaUsuarioActionPerformed(MovimentoAberto.java:403)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.MovimentoAberto.access$200(MovimentoAberto.java:22)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.MovimentoAberto$4.actionPerformed(MovimentoAberto.java:240)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.Caixa.verificarMovimentoExistente(Caixa.java:3392)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.Caixa.<init>(Caixa.java:344)
    at com.t2tierp.pafecf.view.Caixa$41.run(Caixa.java:2393)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As alterações feitas tanto na interface do Java e também no código fonte do Mysql-Connector estão neste repositório:

https://github.com/jackelinesantos/PreparedStatementChanged/tree/master/mysql-5.1.38/src/com/mysql/jdbc

O que devo fazer para que meu método seja chamado no lugar do original já que minha classe está sendo carregada segundo o log?

Comment: Pode adicionar na pergunta o código dessa sua classe?

Comment: Boa pergunta! Só uma dica: `PreparedStatement` é uma interface e não uma classe: _Minhas mudanças foram feitas na classe PreparedStatement_ . [Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: @diegofm o código da PreparedStatement?

Comment: Sim, o código da sua classe que você implementou a interface PrepareStatement e criou um método semelhante a um que já existia.

Comment: @diegofm as alterações do Mysql Connector e da interface do java estão neste repositório: [https://github.com/jackelinesantos/PreparedStatementChanged/tree/master/mysql-5.1.38/src/com/mysql/jdbc]
Quanto as alterações do Java, compilei com o projeto inteiro, mas só deixei no repositório aquilo que sofreu modificação minha.

Answer (score 0):

Ele não encontra o método simplesmente porque sua classe não implementa o método declarado na interface do java.sql.PreparedStatement
que é o método void setBoolean(int parameterIndex, **boolean x**)
veja que o boolean é o primitivo e não o objeto Boolean, então nesse caso você não implementou o método da interface, apenas criou um novo. Então no momento em que o java tenta encontrar uma classe com a implementação do setboolean com primitivo ele não encontra e lança o

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: